# Selecting COUNT and MAX columns with 2 tables and a bridge table

Tags: mysql, sql

so what I am trying to do is having 3 tables (pictures, collections, and bridge) with the following columns:

Collections Table:

```
| id | name      |
------------------
| 1  | coll1     |
| 2  | coll2     |
------------------
```

Pictures Table: (timestamps are unix timestamps)

```
| id | name | timestamp |
-------------------------
| 5  | Pic5 | 1         |
| 6  | Pic6 | 19        | 
| 7  | Pic7 | 3         |
| 8  | Pic8 | 892       |
| 9  | Pic9 | 4         |
-------------------------
```

Bridge Table:

```
| id | collection | picture |
-----------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 5       |
| 2  | 1          | 6       |
| 3  | 1          | 7       |
| 4  | 1          | 8       |
| 5  | 2          | 5       |
| 6  | 2          | 9       |
| 7  | 2          | 7       |
-----------------------------
```

And the result should look like this:

```
| collection_name | picture_count | newest_picture |
----------------------------------------------------
| coll1           | 4             | 8              |
| coll2           | 3             | 9              |
----------------------------------------------------
```

`newest_picture` should always be the picture with the heighest timestamp in that collection and I also want to sort the result by it. `picture_count` is obviously the count of picture in that collection.

Can this be done in a single statement with table joins and if yes:
how can I do this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method uses correlated subqueries:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*)
        from bridge b
        where b.collection = c.id
       ) as pic_count,
       (select p.id
        from bridge b join
             pictures p
             on b.picture = b.id
        where b.collection = c.id
        order by p.timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as most_recent_picture       
from collections c;
```

A more common approach would use window functions:

```
select c.id, c.name, count(bp.collection), bp.most_recent_picture
from collections c left join
     (select b.*,
             first_value(p.id) over (partition by b.collection order by p.timestamp desc) as most_recent_picture
      from bridge b join
           pictures p
           on b.picture = p.id
     ) bp
     on bp.collection = c.id
group by c.id, c.name, bp.most_recent_picture;
```

Comment: I just tried your second query and modified it a little bit (`count(c.collection)` should actually be `count(bp.collection)`) and now it's working just fine.

Also the second query is much faster compared to the first query which takes like 3 seconds for 3000 pictures and like 10 collections on my hardware.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dauerkraut . . . Interesting.  I would expect the first to be faster with indexes on `bridge(collection, picture)` and `pictures(id, timestamp)`.

Comment: Yep, found it. There is a sneaky little `ON b.picture = b.id`. Didn't see it and since there was a second query I didn't bother with it too much and I tried the second one.